# Проверка подключения к MySQL (Java)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysqlconnector

Занимаюсь разработкой собственной *мини-утилиты* для работы с MySQL.
Как я могу проверить подключение к указанному хосту (*по логину и паролю*) без указания* базы данных, как, например, это реализовано в **phpMyAdmin**... Ибо большинство абстракций подключения к MySQL требуют соответственную БД для работы (в частности, **MysqlDataSource**, в моём случае)...

---

*Заранее спасибо)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без указания базы вряд ли получится. Но в **MySql** есть тестовая база `test`. Можно подключиться к ней и сделать тестовый запрос, т.е. `select 1`. Примерно так:

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    String user = "testUser";
    String password = "testPasssword";

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
         Statement st = conn.createStatement();) {
        st.execute("select 1");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //обработка ошибки

        //можно делать дополнительную проверку через
        String sqlState = e.getSQLState();
        //sqlState.equals("...")
    }
```

При неправильном юзере/пароле свалится исключение. К тому же можно дополнительно спарсить `sqlState` из ошибки. Однако стоит учитывать, что администратор БД может запретить возвращать ошибки вида "правильный логин, но неправильный пароль" из-за ограничений безопасности (они будут указываться просто как неправильный **логин или пароль**).